# Node.js sockets, what happen if no FYN packet?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

I have two node.js server, one of them connect via socket to the other and send data regulary.

Exemple could be:

client.js:

```
io = require('socket.io');
var socket = io.connect(IP_SERVER + ':' + PORT);

socket.on('connect', function () {
    setInterval(socket.emit('data', new Date()), 60000);
});
```

server.js

```
var app = http.createServer(),
    io = require('socket.io').listen(app);
app.listen(PORT);
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
    socket.on('data', function(m) {
        console.log(m);
    });
});
```

Now, while the two are communicating, I shut down server.js (ctr-C for example). Is any event pop up in client.js? Is client.js will auto connect once server rebooted?

I ve tried on my own, by adding listener for 'end', 'error' and 'close'. None where started, but once server.js online, it got data anew... Can t I know when this happen?

UPDATE: Well, it seems it end up reconnecting, but the time it take seems random, I can t find anything about this in docs...

Comment: See https://github.com/LearnBoost/Socket.IO/wiki/Configuring-Socket.IO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, it will try to reconnect after losing a connection. There is also a setting (reconnectionDelay) to let socket.io know how long to wait before attempting to reconnect, and there is also a setting (reconnectionDelayMax) that specifies the maximum amount of time to wait between reconnections. Each attempt increases the reconnection by the amount specified by reconnectionDelay.

Full documentation is [here](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io-client#managerurlstring-optsobject)